# How to perform a 301 redirect with .htaccess and PHP

Tags: php, htaccess, seo

The website I am referencing in my question is http://www.bgmenus.com.

I have successfully created clean urls like this for my listings: http://bgmenus.com/five-guys/341

I rewrote those using this: `RewriteRule /([^/.]+)/?$ /restaurants.php?id=$1 [L,NC,QSA]`

The issue is the old URLs still exist and work: http://bgmenus.com/restaurants.php?id=341

My question is how can I **301** the `/restaurants.php?id=123` version of the URL back to the clean version so there aren't any duplicates.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You could also avoid duplicates by setting the canonical link element in the head section.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could check the $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] on the php script restaurants.php if the request url is the correct. For example:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] !== '/' . $name . '/' . $id)
{
    header ('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently');
    header ('Location: http://www.bgmenus.com/' . $name . '/' . $id);
    die();
}
```

Where $name is the restaurant name [five-guys] and $id is the restaurant id [341]

When the hit is from http://bgmenus.com/five-guys/341 the if statement would be false
If someones direct hits /restaurants.php?id=123, the if will be true and the user will be redirected to the new seo friendly url

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get restaurant name from URL since you only have id. 
Just based on id you can use this rule above your existing rule:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+restaurants\.php\?id=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /restaurant/%1? [R=302,L]
```

This redirects `/restaurants.php?id=123` to `/restaurant/123`

Answer (score 0):

Change to this ( "NC" you can remove )

```
RewriteRule /([^/.]+)/?$ /restaurants.php?id=$1 [R=301,L,NC,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

.htaccess has no way of mapping `restaurants.php?id=123` to `/five-guys/341`; it cannot pull the **five guys** slug from the database. You need to do this by coding. Here is a rough outline:

```
// $row variable comes from database
// it might look like
// array("id" => 123, "slug" => "five-guys", "name" => "Five Guys");

$requestedURL = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$preferredURL = '/' . $row['slug'] . '/' . $row['id'];

if ($requestedURL !== $preferredURL) {
    header ($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] . ' 301 Moved Permanently');
    header ('Location: http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $preferredURL);
    die();
}
```

Depending on your server, the original URL might be logged in another server variable. If you are not sure, so a `var_dump($_SERVER)` to locate the variable that contains the *before-rewriting* URL.